# How to change position of a table in vuejs?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Currently it is as follows:

[image]

In fact it was to stay like this;

[image]

I’m having trouble, can anyone help me, please?

This is the source code.

```
<div id="app">



        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Tipo de moeda</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Referencia</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-if="bancodedados" v-for="(val, key) in bancodedados.valores" :key="key">
                <td> {{  val.nome }}  </td> 
                <td> {{  val.valor }}</td>
                <td>{{  val.fonte }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>




</div>
```

Comment: The first screenshot is the default styling from bootstrap, the second is a table without any styling. Documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Comment: I'm relying on documentation.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should return your data horizontally. Otherwise you can define like this.

```
computed: {
  dolar () {
   return this.bancodedados.valores[0].valor;
 },
 euro () {
  return this.bancodedados.valores[1].valor;
 },
 btc () {
  return this.bancodedados.valores[2].valor;
 }
 ...
}
```

or you can use created statement to return data

```
data: {
  dolar: 0,
  euro: 0,
  btc: 0
},
created() {
  this.dolar = this.bancodedados.valores[0].valor;
  this.euro = this.bancodedados.valores[1].valor;
  this.btc = this.bancodedados.valores[2].valor
 ...
}
```

your table should like this in both cases

```
<table class="table">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Dola</th>
     <th>Euro</th>
     <th>BTC</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td> {{ dolar }} </td>
      <td> {{ euro }} </td>
      <td> {{ btc }} </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```